# Find location of a variable

Tags: r

The variables "cars" and "pressure" are defined by default in my R environment. How can I find out where they are defined? These are not functions

I want to use my own variables and packages in RMarkdown and hence I need to know where these are coming from.

Since I stumbled upon these variables while learning RMarkdown, I thought the RMarkdown package defines this. But these variables remain even in a new R session where the markdown library is not installed.

Possibly these are defined in the base package - I need to know where exactly and how to find that out.

Comment: Try `datasets::`. As a note, if you find an answer useful, you have the ability to accept it if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can find them using

```
datasets::cars
datasets::pressure
```

My favourite function with a bit more information:

```
getAnywhere("cars")
```

Result(truncated)

```
A single object matching ‘cars’ was found
It was found in the following places
  package:datasets
with value
```

Answer (score 0):

Datasets should be documented. Typing `?cars` in the console will open the help page of the data set. In the top-left corner it shows "cars {datasets}" indicating that `cars` is located in the `datasets` package.